# Not able to detect hangup for indian numbers in asterisk 10

Tags: asterisk

I am not able to detect hangup event when I am using Indian numbers but for USA numbers the the hangup is detected. If an indian number is connected and he is in a conference (confbridge) then if he hangup his phone then the hangup event is not fired.

Please help.

Comment: What channel are u trying this on ?

Comment: trying with sip channel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a SIP channel... You could try to detect the hangup based on the RTP timeout.

The setting in your `[device]` or globally, is:

`rtptimeout=60`

Which is the default, 60 seconds. You could crank this down a lot lower if it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

That depend of provider used. Change sip provider/or choose more costly plan. Hangup detection in this case have be handled by provider's equipment.